# WARN [LocalManagedConnectionFactory:cleanup] Lock owned during cleanup:

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jboss, jboss-eap-6

We are seeing the following WARN on Jboss EAP 6.20 Beta1

```
2014-04-01 03:00:00,539 WARN  [LocalManagedConnectionFactory:cleanup] Lock owned during cleanup: EJB default - 7: java.lang.Throwable: Lock owned during cleanup: EJB default - 7
```

However the exact same code and setup running on Jboss EAP 6.0.1 doesn't produce this error.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this exception on Jboss EAP 6.20 Beta1?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to encounter the same problem and to find a short explanation here (that matched my situation): https://access.redhat.com/solutions/467903

Mainly it says that the root cause of the problem is the following:

> Blockquote
>   Those warnings indicate that a connection is being used by two different threads concurrently. The second thread is attempting to close a connection, but there are active locks on it. The first thread is the one that is holding the lock on the connection.
>   Blockquote